# extract substring after the first underscore

Tags: c#, split, substring

I need to remove the underscore and all characters before it in my filename.  The syntax of the filename is as follows:

```
<username>_<NameofFile>_<InstructorName>_<ClassName>.xls
```

I want to keep everything BUT the `<username>_` part.
I tried using `.Split` as follows:

```
string newfilename = file.Split('_')[1];
```

but that dropped everything and only kept `<NameOfFile>`.
How could this be achieved?

Comment: Can your usernames have underscores in them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string newfilename = file.Substring(file.IndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Comment: I think this is your best bet. You could also do it with `String.Remove(0, i + 1)`, but that will be slower than `String.Substring()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Split` method has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to specify the maximum number of substrings to split into.

```
string newfilename = file.Split(new [] { '_' }, 2).Last();
```

Also, I'd suggest using `Last()`, instead of `[1]`, so as to get the full string when there aren't any underscores.